# Is it possible to use Slick 3 for accessing different schemas within the same Database?

Tags: multi-tenant, slick, slick-3.0

For a multi tenant application I need to create I want to evaluate how convenient is Slick for creating queries against Postgres different schemas (not to confuse with schema tables).

I'm having a hard time finding how to configure `TableQuery` to use dynamically the schema provided by the user. `TableQuery[Users].resul` should return different datasets depending on me querying tenant A or tenant B.

Is it possible with current Slick versions?

Answer (score 0):

`TableQuery` itself will not need to be configured, as its methods only return queries and actions. Actions are run by a `DatabaseDef` instance, and that is what will need to be configured to access different schemas/databases/etc. Slick official documentation [describes](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/database.html) a simple way to create an instance of a `DatabaseDef`, which by default uses the [Typesage Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library:

```scala
val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
```

where `"mydb"` specifies a key in a property file Typesafe Config is looking at. You can create and manipulate `Config` instances programmatically as well, and create `db` instances from those. I suspect you will have to do something along the lines of creating a new `Config` instance (there is the convenient `withValue()` method to copy a `Config` and replace a config value at the specified key) and use that to create a new `db` instance for each new schema you are interested in querying.